# Sum total by hour & calculate percentage efficiency

Tags: sql, sql-server, time

Newbie on SQL. I'm trying to come up with a way, to sum up, how many goods packed by machine on an hourly basis within a period of time.

I have 2 tables:

1. Session table - store job start & end time
2. Record table  - store data on how many product packed by machine recorded by user every 5 or 10 minutes

Session Table

```
SES_ID   SES_NOTE         SES_START           SES_END
  1     A000000001  2017-04-21 07:10:20  2017-04-21 15:10:10
  2     A000000078  2017-04-21 15:20:33  2017-04-21 23:10:25
```

Sample Record Table:

```
       TIME           REC_NOTE     SKU        TOTAL    SES_NOTE
2017-04-21 07:10:20  A000000001  ABC1234567    90     A000000001
2017-04-21 07:15:11  A000000002  ABC1234567    97     A000000001
2017-04-21 07:20:33  A000000003  ABC1234567    80     A000000001
2017-04-21 07:30:06  A000000004  ABC1234567    111    A000000001
2017-04-21 07:40:23  A000000005  ABC1234567    120    A000000001
2017-04-21 07:45:44  A000000006  ABC1234567    89     A000000001
2017-04-21 07:50:18  A000000007  ABC1234567    92     A000000001
2017-04-21 08:00:15  A000000008  ABC1234567    87     A000000001
2017-04-21 08:05:01  A000000009  ABC1234567    95     A000000001
2017-04-21 08:10:22  A000000010  ABC1234567    99     A000000001
2017-04-24 08:20:38  A000000011  ABC1234567    126    A000000001
2017-04-21 08:30:50  A000000012  ABC1234568    118    A000000001
2017-04-21 08:40:27  A000000013  ABC1234567    130    A000000001
2017-04-21 08:45:48  A000000014  ABC1234567    89     A000000001
2017-04-21 08:50:36  A000000015  ABC1234567    99     A000000001
2017-04-21 09:00:58  A000000016  ABC1234567    98     A000000001
2017-04-21 09:05:54  A000000017  ABC1234567    89     A000000001
2017-04-21 09:10:12  A000000018  ABC1234567    95     A000000001
2017-04-21 09:20:29  A000000019  ABC1234567    99     A000000001
2017-04-21 09:25:25  A000000020  ABC1234567    99     A000000001
2017-04-21 09:30:29  A000000021  ABC1234567    100    A000000001
2017-04-21 09:40:45  A000000022  ABC1234567    130    A000000001
2017-04-21 09:50:31  A000000023  ABC1234567    120    A000000001
2017-04-21 10:00:02  A000000024  ABC1234567    110    A000000001
2017-04-21 10:05:05  A000000025  ABC1234567    111    A000000001
2017-04-21 10:10:23  A000000026  ABC1234567    77     A000000001
2017-04-21 10:15:56  A000000027  ABC1234567    69     A000000001
2017-04-21 10:20:01  A000000028  ABC1234567    80     A000000001
2017-04-21 10:25:02  A000000029  ABC1234567    85     A000000001
2017-04-21 10:30:07  A000000030  ABC1234567    89     A000000001
2017-04-21 10:35:09  A000000031  ABC1234567    80     A000000001
2017-04-21 10:40:13  A000000032  ABC1234567    60     A000000001
2017-04-21 10:50:41  A000000033  ABC1234567    120    A000000001
2017-04-21 10:55:48  A000000034  ABC1234567    59     A000000001
2017-04-21 11:00:10  A000000035  ABC1234567    78     A000000001
2017-04-21 11:05:23  A000000036  ABC1234567    82     A000000001
2017-04-21 11:10:11  A000000037  ABC1234567    99     A000000001
2017-04-21 11:20:26  A000000038  ABC1234567    119    A000000001
2017-04-21 11:25:33  A000000039  ABC1234567    75     A000000001
2017-04-21 11:30:56  A000000040  ABC1234567    76     A000000001
2017-04-21 11:35:43  A000000041  ABC1234567    67     A000000001
2017-04-21 11:40:24  A000000042  ABC1234567    84     A000000001
2017-04-21 11:50:12  A000000043  ABC1234567    99     A000000001
2017-04-21 11:55:28  A000000044  ABC1234567    74     A000000001
2017-04-21 12:00:01  A000000045  ABC1234568    80     A000000001
2017-04-21 12:05:04  A000000046  ABC1234568    77     A000000001
2017-04-21 12:10:17  A000000047  ABC1234568    90     A000000001
2017-04-21 12:20:41  A000000048  ABC1234568    89     A000000001
2017-04-21 12:25:11  A000000049  ABC1234568    88     A000000001
2017-04-21 12:30:54  A000000050  ABC1234567    90     A000000001
2017-04-21 12:35:31  A000000051  ABC1234567    79     A000000001
2017-04-21 12:40:21  A000000052  ABC1234567    90     A000000001
2017-04-21 12:50:14  A000000053  ABC1234567    80     A000000001
2017-04-21 12:55:09  A000000054  MB145103632   90     A000000001
2017-04-21 13:00:02  A000000055  ABC1234567    93     A000000001
2017-04-21 13:05:08  A000000056  ABC1234567    90     A000000001
2017-04-21 13:10:50  A000000057  ABC1234567    70     A000000001
2017-04-21 13:20:44  A000000058  ABC1234567    65     A000000001
2017-04-21 13:25:37  A000000059  ABC1234567    90     A000000001
2017-04-21 13:30:12  A000000060  ABC1234567    89     A000000001
2017-04-21 13:35:23  A000000061  ABC1234567    70     A000000001
2017-04-21 13:40:41  A000000062  ABC1234567    78     A000000001
2017-04-21 13:50:13  A000000063  ABC1234567    120    A000000001
2017-04-21 13:55:13  A000000064  ABC1234567    85     A000000001
2017-04-21 14:00:09  A000000065  ABC1234567    77     A000000001
2017-04-21 14:05:00  A000000066  ABC1234567    86     A000000001
2017-04-21 14:10:49  A000000067  ABC1234567    80     A000000001
2017-04-21 14:15:18  A000000068  ABC1234567    91     A000000001
2017-04-21 14:20:13  A000000069  ABC1234568    65     A000000001
2017-04-21 14:25:19  A000000070  ABC1234568    80     A000000001
2017-04-21 14:30:48  A000000071  ABC1234568    80     A000000001
2017-04-21 14:35:37  A000000072  ABC1234568    71     A000000001
2017-04-21 14:40:44  A000000073  ABC1234567    75     A000000001
2017-04-21 14:50:51  A000000074  ABC1234568    77     A000000001
2017-04-21 14:55:27  A000000075  ABC1234568    76     A000000001
2017-04-21 15:00:35  A000000076  ABC1234567    69     A000000001
2017-04-21 15:10:10  A000000077  ABC1234568    79     A000000001
2017-04-21 15:20:33  A000000078  ABC1234567    99     A000000078
2017-04-21 15:25:06  A000000079  ABC1234568    80     A000000078
2017-04-21 15:30:23  A000000080  ABC1234568    82     A000000078
2017-04-21 15:35:44  A000000081  ABC1234567    70     A000000078
2017-04-21 15:40:18  A000000082  ABC1234568    60     A000000078
2017-04-21 15:50:15  A000000083  ABC1234567    99     A000000078
2017-04-21 15:55:01  A000000084  ABC1234567    111    A000000078
2017-04-21 16:00:22  A000000085  ABC1234567    74     A000000078
2017-04-24 16:05:38  A000000086  ABC1234567    81     A000000078
2017-04-21 16:10:50  A000000087  ABC1234567    85     A000000078
2017-04-21 16:20:27  A000000088  ABC1234567    84     A000000078
2017-04-21 16:30:48  A000000089  ABC1234567    136    A000000078
2017-04-21 16:40:36  A000000090  ABC1234567    114    A000000078
2017-04-21 16:45:58  A000000091  ABC1234567    106    A000000078
2017-04-21 16:50:54  A000000092  10304201      83     A000000078
2017-04-21 16:55:12  A000000093  10304201      60     A000000078
2017-04-21 17:00:29  A000000094  10304201      89     A000000078
2017-04-21 17:05:25  A000000095  10304201      99     A000000078
2017-04-21 17:10:29  A000000096  10304201      99     A000000078
2017-04-21 17:20:45  A000000097  10304201      73     A000000078
2017-04-21 17:30:31  A000000098  10304202A     120    A000000078
2017-04-21 17:35:02  A000000099  18312101      125    A000000078
2017-04-21 17:40:05  A000000100  18314402      75     A000000078
2017-04-21 17:45:23  A000000101  18312101      60     A000000078
2017-04-21 17:50:56  A000000102  10304202T     76     A000000078
2017-04-21 17:55:01  A000000103  10304201      64     A000000078
2017-04-21 18:00:02  A000000104  10304201      79     A000000078
2017-04-21 18:05:07  A000000105  10304201      80     A000000078
2017-04-21 18:10:25  A000000106  10304201      75     A000000078
2017-04-21 18:20:29  A000000107  10304201      70     A000000078
2017-04-21 18:25:45  A000000108  10304202T     89     A000000078
2017-04-21 18:30:31  A000000109  ABC1234567    79     A000000078
2017-04-21 18:35:02  A000000110  ABC1234567    89     A000000078
2017-04-21 18:40:05  A000000111  ABC1234567    68     A000000078
2017-04-21 18:50:23  A000000112  ABC1234567    70     A000000078
2017-04-21 18:55:56  A000000113  ABC1234567    130    A000000078
2017-04-21 19:00:01  A000000114  ABC1234567    77     A000000078
2017-04-21 19:05:07  A000000115  ABC1234567    60     A000000078
2017-04-21 19:10:25  A000000116  ABC1234567    111    A000000078
2017-04-21 19:20:29  A000000117  ABC1234567    85     A000000078
2017-04-21 19:25:45  A000000118  ABC1234567    84     A000000078
2017-04-21 19:30:31  A000000119  ABC1234567    73     A000000078
2017-04-21 19:35:02  A000000120  ABC1234567    80     A000000078
2017-04-21 19:40:05  A000000121  ABC1234567    69     A000000078
2017-04-21 19:50:23  A000000122  ABC1234567    70     A000000078
2017-04-21 19:55:56  A000000123  ABC1234567    120    A000000078
2017-04-21 20:00:01  A000000124  ABC1234567    77     A000000078
2017-04-21 20:05:07  A000000125  ABC1234567    83     A000000078
2017-04-21 20:10:25  A000000126  ABC1234567    117    A000000078
2017-04-21 20:20:29  A000000127  ABC1234567    83     A000000078
2017-04-21 20:25:45  A000000128  ABC1234567    79     A000000078
2017-04-21 20:30:31  A000000129  ABC1234567    66     A000000078
2017-04-21 20:35:02  A000000130  ABC1234567    65     A000000078
2017-04-21 20:40:05  A000000131  ABC1234567    80     A000000078
2017-04-21 20:50:23  A000000132  ABC1234567    74     A000000078
2017-04-21 20:55:56  A000000133  ABC1234567    120    A000000078
2017-04-21 21:00:01  A000000134  ABC1234567    87     A000000078
2017-04-21 21:05:07  A000000135  ABC1234567    81     A000000078
2017-04-21 21:10:25  A000000136  ABC1234567    130    A000000078
2017-04-21 21:20:29  A000000137  ABC1234567    78     A000000078
2017-04-21 21:25:45  A000000138  ABC1234567    85     A000000078
2017-04-21 21:30:31  A000000139  ABC1234567    64     A000000078
2017-04-21 21:35:02  A000000140  ABC1234567    76     A000000078
2017-04-21 21:40:05  A000000141  ABC1234567    86     A000000078
2017-04-21 21:50:23  A000000142  ABC1234567    76     A000000078
2017-04-21 21:55:56  A000000143  ABC1234567    135    A000000078
2017-04-21 22:00:01  A000000144  ABC1234567    66     A000000078
2017-04-21 22:05:07  A000000145  ABC1234567    50     A000000078
2017-04-21 22:10:25  A000000146  ABC1234567    126    A000000078
2017-04-21 22:20:29  A000000147  ABC1234567    88     A000000078
2017-04-21 22:25:45  A000000148  ABC1234567    68     A000000078
2017-04-21 22:30:31  A000000149  ABC1234567    79     A000000078
2017-04-21 22:35:02  A000000150  ABC1234567    89     A000000078
2017-04-21 22:40:05  A000000151  ABC1234567    85     A000000078
2017-04-21 22:50:23  A000000152  ABC1234567    77     A000000078
2017-04-21 22:55:56  A000000153  ABC1234567    90     A000000078
2017-04-21 23:00:01  A000000154  ABC1234567    87     A000000078
2017-04-21 23:05:07  A000000155  ABC1234567    74     A000000078
2017-04-21 23:10:25  A000000156  ABC1234567    121    A000000078
```

From the sample table, I want to determine:

1. a sum of TOTAL per hour.
2. the packing machine efficiency per hour. Assume the machine can pack product per hour is 880, efficiency will be= (sum of TOTAL per hour) * 100 / 880

Result will be like below format:

```
     Time         Total  Mach_Speed  Efficiency (%)
2017-04-21 07:00   960      880          109.09
```

Appreciate anyone can help on this.

Comment: I'm having difficulty seeing where the session table data comes in. Your result looks like it's just grouped on date and hour. Is the idea that any times in your other table which don't fall between one of the explicit date ranges from the session table are ignored?

Comment: From where you are getting cutting speed? Is your explanation different from example data?

Answer (score 0):

Untested SQL Server 2012 syntax:

```
SELECT      DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(TIME), MONTH(TIME), DAY(TIME), DATEPART(HOUR, TIME), 0, 0, 0)    AS [Hour]
        ,   SUM(TOTAL)                                                                              AS [Total]
FROM        Records
GROUP BY    DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(TIME), MONTH(TIME), DAY(TIME), DATEPART(HOUR, TIME), 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: error stated " 'HOUR' is not a recognized built-in function name". I'm using MS SQL Express 2014 ver 12.0.2269.0